# $\mathbf{E}_n$-algebras in nerves of 2-categories

Tags: reference-request, infinity-categories, operads, 2-categories

In Example 5.1.2.4 of [Higher Algebra](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/papers/HA.pdf), Lurie explains how there is a bijection between equivalence classes braided monoidal structures on one-category $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathbf{E}_2$-algebra structures on the nerve $\text{N}(\mathcal{C})$. Likewise for $\mathbf{E}_n$, $n\ge 0$.

---

*Pre-question:* how does one interpret this as an equivalence of categories, e.g.  is the stronger thing true
$$\text{N}_2(\textbf{E}_n\text{-Alg}(\text{1-Cat}))\ \stackrel{?}{\simeq}\ \textbf{E}_n\text{-Alg}(\text{N}_2(\text{1-Cat}))\ =\ \textbf{E}_n\text{-Alg}(\textbf{1-Cat})?$$
Here where $\text{N}_2$ is the [nerve](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.01999)  of the 2-category $\text{1-Cat}$, $\textbf{1-Cat}\subseteq \text{Cat}_\infty$, and (I think?) $\text{N}_2(\text{1-Cat}) \stackrel{}{=} \textbf{1-Cat}$.

---

My **question** is then: if we replace $\text{1-Cat}$ with an arbitrary 2-category $\mathcal{E}$, is the above pre-question (or a salvage thereof) still true?